# Converting html elements to an javascript array and then printing them back on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few `<div>` elements in my HTML page that I've converted into a javascript array.

I've randomized the array and now I need to print it back on the page. How can I do that?
Here's the code

```js
let fields = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-2')
let fieldsArr = Array.from(fields);
let randFields = fieldsArr.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random()
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="6">6</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="7">7</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="8">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="9">9</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="10">10</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="11">11</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="12">12</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="13">13</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="14">14</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="15">15</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="16">16</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="17">17</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="18">18</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="19">19</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="20">20</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="21">21</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="22">22</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="23">23</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="24">24</div>
</div>
```

Displaying randFields on the page, gives me back 24
`[object HTMLDivElement]`.

Comment: Displaying how?

Comment: You can't print directly an item from your HTMLCollection. Use appendChild();

Comment: I have another div with an id of " show". I've tried doing this:
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = randFields

Comment: I've tried the appendChild method and it just gives me back an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: So you want to keep the original elements and show also them in a new order?

Comment: select .row and append elements as childs to it in loop

Comment: No, I'm just gonna hide them. I'm keeping the original one just for testing .

Comment: So you're saying that I loop through the randFields and append that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the randomly re-ordered divs in the DOM you need to call `appendChild()` on their parent and pass the element reference as an argument. You can achieve that in a `forEach()` loop over the array resulting from the `sort()` call, like this:

```js
let row = document.querySelector('.row');
let fields = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-2')
let fieldsArr = Array.from(fields);

fieldsArr.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).forEach(function(el) {
  row.appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="6">6</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="7">7</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="8">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="9">9</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="10">10</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="11">11</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="12">12</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="13">13</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="14">14</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="15">15</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="16">16</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="17">17</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="18">18</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="19">19</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="20">20</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="21">21</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="22">22</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="23">23</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="24">24</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thanks mate! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an array of your divs randomized, I will just print each of them one by one to elem with class of .row

```
let container = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].innerHTML = '';

randFields.forEach( elem =>  {
  container.innerHTML += elem;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let fields = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-2')
let fieldsArr = Array.from(fields);
let randFields = fieldsArr.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random()
});
html = '';
for(i in randFields){
    html += randFields[i].outerHTML;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].outerHTML = html
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="6">6</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="7">7</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="8">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="9">9</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="10">10</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="11">11</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="12">12</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="13">13</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="14">14</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="15">15</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="16">16</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="17">17</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="18">18</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="19">19</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="20">20</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="21">21</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="22">22</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="23">23</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="24">24</div>
</div>

And JavaScript:
```